# Convert matrix in string format into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing arrays in HTML as a string

```
<div id='foo'>['A', 'B', [['C', 1, 2]]]</div>
```

What I want

```
var myArray = ['A', 'B', [['C', 1, 2]]];
```

I've been trying to grab it with something like `$("#foo").text();` then convert it to a Javascript variable. Normally I'd just use `data.split(',')`, however with the sub array, things get messed up. I'd like to not use `eval()`. How can I convert this string into a js array?

Comment: If this is a bad question, how can I make it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the single quotes to double quotes, and use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the string to convert to an array:

```js
const result = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#foo')
  .innerText
  .replace(/'/g, '"'));
  
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id='foo'>['A', 'B', [['C', 1, 2]]]</div>
```

Comment: That was it. I was getting stuck on the `.replace(/'/g, '"'));` part. Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

```
var myArray = $('#foo').textContent
```

will get the values as a string and put in your variable. Do realize this does not convert it to Array. Do you really need it as array or as string?